# Adding p values with "p = ___" to a ggplot

Tags: r

I'm working on a project where I need to create a boxplot that shows the p values between different treatments. I'm able to add the numeric p values but my supervisor wants them to be formatted to include "p = " before the number. I've attempted to use the glue function, geom_text() to add text in, and manipulating the labels directly but these attempts haven't been successful.

I'd appreciate any tips and advice.

Thanks,

Simon

Comment: Please show a small reproducible sample of data as well as the code you tried. I would think something like `geom_text(aes(label = glue("p = {name_of_you_p_value_column}")))` would work. But I would also think that's what you tried, so we need more information to figure out what might have gone wrong.

Comment: The nicest way to share sample data is with `dput`, e.g., `dput(your_data[1:10, ])` for the first 10 rows. It's copy/pasteable into R and includes all structure and class information.

Comment: What Gregor said about reprodudible example.  I usually just create a string in the passed dataset as a new variable.  So I create a variable `mydf$mypvalue = paste0("p = ",round(mydf$p_value,4))` and then use that as the ggplot2 label.